# Dark theme on nemo

Tags: 22.04, themes, color-management

[image]New Linux user here. I have a dark theme on Ubuntu 22.04 but Nemo 5.24 it does not show up. Is there anyway to set a dark theme in Nemo? I saw an answer to a question similar to mine but it was made long time ago and it did not seem to work for me.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface color-scheme prefer-dark`

Comment: I tried this just now, but it did not change anything, do I have to do something after that, like logging out?

Comment: Just FYI, this works natively in Linux Mint, which is based on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to achieve a dark theme in `Nemo` by changing the system theme in `Gnome Tweaks`.

To install `Gnome Tweaks`:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

When you open the application you will see something like this:

[image: Gnome Tweaks App]

Navigate to `Appearance -> Styles -> Legacy Application`. By default The theme should be "Yaru". In the drop down menu, find Yaru-Dark (it might be close to the bottom) and press it:

[image: Yaru Dark]

Now `Nemo` should look like this:

[image: Nemo]

There are a lot of other themes. I would recommend to experiment until you find one you like. There is also the option to [install other themes](https://itsfoss.com/install-themes-ubuntu/).

*Helpful links:*

*[Gnome Tweaks](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-tweak-tool/)*

Comment: sorry but my gnome tweaks looks different. Appearnce starts with Applications and ends with adjustments, nothing there about legacy applications.

Comment: @amar Could you share an image of your gnome tweaks?

Comment: @amar Try to change your "Applications" to be "Yaru-dark" or other themes that are available. Does that work?

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to send an image here, I just copied it but when i post it it is the filepath and name. My application is already yaru dark, I will change it to something else.

Comment: @amar Sorry but I can't access files on your computer. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1507899/edit)
 your post to contain the image.

Comment: @amar You can just copy and paste the image

Comment: that is what copy and paste does, in image viewr, any program that works+

Comment: [How to add images into askubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1396/how-do-i-add-images-to-posts) Don't add it into your comments but into your question

Comment: @amar What you need to do is just paste the same line you gave me before but into you question. You can edit it by pressing "edit" right at the end of your question

Comment: @amar I see you have edited your question. You have changed the theme to be "Yaru-Dark" Does `Nemo` now have a dark theme or not?

Comment: yes I do in natilus and other things but not in nemo, I just tried gwenview and it is not in dark mode either, so dark mode works on some applications and not in others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152116/discussion-between-john-carter-and-amar).

Answer (score 1):

I had chosen high contrast in setting, accessibilty, once i turend it off, and ran GTK_THEME=yaru-dark nemo in terminal it fixed nemo.
[image]

Comment: It is good that you have found a solution!

Comment: On Debian 12 (bookworm) and Nemo 5.6 the following fixed for me: open Gnome Tweeks -> Appearence. Then choose Adwaita-Dark for "Legacy Applications" field (Themes section)